# Looping hash but showing the entire set in last loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in Rails 3.2:

```
Changeset: <%= @version.changeset %><br><br>

Length: <%= @version.changeset.length %><br><br>

<%= @version.changeset.each_with_index do |(key, value), i| %>
  <%= i %> - <%= key %> - <%= value %><br>
<% end %>
```

Output is:

```
Changeset: {"getting_there"=>["a", "b"], "description"=>["c", "d"]}

Length: 2

0 - getting_there - ["a", "b"]
1 - description - ["c", "d"]
{"getting_there"=>["a", "b"], "description"=>["c", "d"]}
```

I have no idea why the last `{"getting_there"=>["a", "b"], "description"=>["c", "d"]}` is showing. It shouldn't be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<%= @version.changeset.each_with_index do |(key, value), i| %>
```

you need to have:

```
<% @version.changeset.each_with_index do |(key, value), i| %>
```

This `=` means that in the end value of `each_with_index` call (which is hash on which you call this) will be displayed.

Comment: Argh... mistake. Thanks.